# Liquibase Generate databasechangelog including tablespace name attributes

Tags: liquibase

How can I perform the databasechangelog generation and include the tablespacename attribute, I see that the attribute exists on createTable but in my generated file the attribute isn't available.

Liquibase 3.4.x

Comment: I might be wrong on this but I think the serializer that writes the XML does not respect the db schema. In other words: This functionality is not included.

Comment: I am assuming this because the [`XMLChangeLogSerializer.serialize(LiquibaseSerializable, boolean)`](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/master/liquibase-core/src/main/java/liquibase/serializer/core/xml/XMLChangeLogSerializer.java) only takes [`LiquibaseSerializable`](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/master/liquibase-core/src/main/java/liquibase/serializer/LiquibaseSerializable.java) objects and not [`DatabaseObject`](https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/blob/master/liquibase-core/src/main/java/liquibase/structure/DatabaseObject.java) objects which has a schema attribute.